# как вывести в списке профили так чтобы у кого среднее число звезд у отзывов больше тот выше в списке?Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
  У каждого профиля есть отзывы с разным количеством звезд

нужно расставить профили так чтобы у кого среднее число звезд у отзывов больше тот выше
```

у отзывов есть поле rating по нему и нужно сортировать

```
   class Profile extends Model
    {
       public function reviews() {
            return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
        }
    }
    
    class PageController extends Controller
    {
      public function painting(Request $request)
    {
       $rating = $request->rating;
       $profiles = Profile::where('status', '1')
                    ->when($rating, function ($query) {
                        return $query->reviews->orderBy('среднее число звезд', 'desc');
                    })->paginate(20);
    }
    }
```

спасибо!

Comment: Laravel тут не при чём. Смотрите, как составлять такой запрос (Вам нужны `GROUP BY` и `AVG()`)

Comment: @ Vladimir Gonchar дело в то что мнеинужно это же вставить в ->when($rating, function ($query) {} поэтому laravel причем

Comment: Вы сначала постройте запрос нормально без всего на чистом SQL, а потом уже будет всё понятно, что и куда.